# Column_layout does not work in android tablelayout

Tags: java, android

mistake in tablelayout in android. The issue is that I want to move button to the 1 column in the second row using property column_layout in 2 tablerow. I have found the solution. please,check my answer.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".TableLayoutActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
      <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/firstButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/myFirstbtn"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/ThirdButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/myThirdbtn"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/FourthButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/myFourthbtn"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
            <Button android:id="@+id/secButton"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="@string/mySecbtn"/>
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed weight property and removed android:layout_width="0dp". I have insert android:layout_width="wrap_content" instead. Problem is solved.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TableLayoutActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >
<TableRow>
    <Button android:id="@+id/firstButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="@string/myFirstbtn"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/ThirdButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/myThirdbtn"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/FourthButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/myFourthbtn"/>
</TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/secButton"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="@string/mySecbtn"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```